# Loop through a text file with an input

Tags: python, loops, text-files

I have a text file set out in this layout:

> Greg,Computer Science,Hard,5
>
> Alex,Computer Science,Medium,2
>
> Fiona,Maths,Easy,0
>
> Cassie,Maths,Medium,5
>
> Alex,Maths,Medium,1

In my program I want the user to be able to choose a certain name and see their results. My code for this looks like this:

```
name = input("Enter name: ")
for each in file:
    each = each.split(",")
    realName = each[0]
    subject = each[1]
    difficulty = each[2]
    score = each[3]
    if name == realName:
        print(subject, difficulty, score)
        break
else:
    print()
    print("Invalid name.")
    name = input("Re-enter your name: ")
```

A few things are wrong with it though and I can't figure out what to do:

1. If the user entered "Alex", only one of his results will be displayed.
2. If a wrong name is inputted once, every other name inputted will return as "Invalid".
3. If the correct name is inputted and the results are displayed, the program will continue to ask for a name.

Does anybody have any solutions to these problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're going to query your file repeatedly, I'd recommend pre-loading your data once into a dictionary, and printing data as and when needed. Something like this:

```
data = {}
with open('file.txt', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        realName, subject, difficulty, score = each.split(',') 
        data.setdefault(realName, []).append((subject, difficulty, score))

while True:
    name = input('>>> ')
    data.get(name, 'Invalid Name')
```

This solves problems one and two. If you just want to break after the first valid name is input, you can query the return value of `dict.get`:

```
while True:
    name = input('>>> ')
    result = data.get(name)
    if result:
        print(result)
        break

    print('Invalid name')
```

This solves problem three.

Comment: I'm quite new to python so I'm not sure what line 5 is saying. Also when I copied that into my program and ran it, it gave `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'setdefault'`.

Comment: @GregD'Silva Ah, shucks. It should've been `{}`, not `[]`. See edit.

Comment: The details of Alex now return as `[('Computer Science', 'Medium', '2\n'), ('Maths', 'Medium', '1')]` rather than on separate lines without all of the brackets.

Comment: @GregD'Silva So? Isn't that a step in the right direction? I've got you this far. Surely you can figure out the rest yourself. Your question isn't even concerned about output representation.

Answer (score 0):

You're better off using the [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) since your file syntax is simple CSV.

Then you can loop through the rows (each row will be an array of values).

```
import csv

def parse_csv_file(csv_file, operation, value, index):
    with open(csv_file, newline='') as file:
        reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=',',
                            quotechar='|')
        return operation(reader,
                        value, index)


def find_first_row(csv_reader, value, index):
    for row in csv_reader:
        if row[index] == value:
            return row
    return None


def main():

    query = input('Enter a name: ')

    result = parse_csv_file('file.csv',
                            find_first_row,
                            query, 0)

    if result:
        print(result)
    else:
        print('Nothing found!')

main()
```

Comment: Switching to CSV to parse OP's file does not solve their immediate problem.

Comment: Added example code that shows how to parse the CSV.